# Editing Skydrive synced storage on web

Tags: windows, onedrive

I have installed Windows Live Mesh from Windows Live Essentials. I've synced a folder "Test" containing couple of word documents with Skydrive. I opened skydrive.live.com and logged in. On the left pane, I clicked 'Files' and selected 'View synced folders' and I found the folder "Test" I synced from my PC. Now, how to edit the documents in Web? If the question is unclear, please let me know. I'll attach screenshots to further explain the problem.

Comment: Okay, After reading
http://www.wysiwygmedia.com/reviews/windows-live-mesh-2011-and-skydrive-synced-storage-woven-together-nicely-still-a-few-of-loose-threads.wm

I just found out that this is not possible. As the author points out, may be Microsoft doesn't want to cannibalize the sales of Office suite.

Comment: It doesn't look that well integrated.  Which is a shame. I've always used WebDAV to mount the Skydrive as a shared folder on all my PCs.

Comment: I read a few posts in Microsoft forums, that this feature 'Integrating Skydrive office web apps' with 'synced storage' is most requested. If microsoft is all about 'Putting people first', then they should do this integration as soon as possible

Comment: Meh. "Putting people first" is more than just adding arbitrary features.

Comment: How come it is an arbitrary feature? If I have the capability to edit the file online using Office web apps, why would I bother buying retail copy of Office suite? It is the most requested feature

Comment: It's an arbitrary feature because people want more.  They don't want to JUST edit all their documents online. We want our application state to follow us from machine to machine.  The webapps is a sideshow compared to true user state virtualization. Free isn't the answer.

Comment: Okay, now you lost me completely. Kindly explain what user state virtualization is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SkyDrive Synced Storage (5 GB) associated with Live Mesh does not integrate into the other SkyDrive located at `skydrive.live.com` (25 GB).
regarding the storage,SkyDrive Synced Storage (5 GB)  is included in the `skydrive.live.com` (25 GB).

The only point of "integration" is a link to `View Synced Folders` within the SkyDrive that will show any folders synced to `SkyDrive Synced Storage` within the Live Mesh program. The two really are separate services even though they share the SkyDrive name. Quite unfortunate and confusing.

Files in SkyDrive can be edited using Office Web Apps, while files in SkyDrive Sync Storage from Live Mesh cannot (for no reason other than they aren't in the SkyDrive itself).

Comment: Yup, figured that out after some time.